# How do i write this piece of code in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How do i write this piece of javascript code in Jquery

```
<script>
function init() {                

    alert('hi: ');
}

var previousOnload = window.onload;        
window.onload = function() { 
    if (previousOnload) { 
        previousOnload();
    }

    init();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Side question: How do you exit this? It seems that it constantly calls itself?

Comment: This is not a Code-Writing-service, this is a Question & Answer site. Do you have a specific question? Or at least show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you don't have to "remember" the previous onload, both the window onload and the jQuery onload will run:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        WriteLine("window onload");
    };

    $(function() {
        WriteLine("jQuery onload");
    });

    function WriteLine(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
</script>
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/SXQmT/

Comment: the reason i am doing this is in salesforce i would not be able to write my onload function like we do it in normal html pages. the hack mentioned to load our own function was using the code i had posted. So i guess its required that we need to remember the previous onload

Comment: @Prady no you can use `$(function() { /* code here */ });` and it will be *added* without overwriting the original onload.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
function LoadEvent(Func)
{
    var OldOnLoad = window.onload;
    if (typeof OldOnLoad != 'function')
    {
        window.onload = Func;
    }else{
        window.onload = function()
        {
            OldOnLoad();
            Func();
        }
    }
}
```

And then use like so:

```
LoadEvent(Init);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(window).load(init)` would do almost the same thing.  but without having `previousOnload` cluttering things up.  It'll remember the previous onload for you, and call both when the page is fully loaded.